# is it possible to Define CI APPPATH in virtual host or htaccess?

Tags: codeigniter, constants

I'm having some weird APPPATH issues due to differences between OS X and Debian installs of PHP and Apache. I do not want to modify any CI files due to the differences between my development vs production environments.

Is it possible to define APPPATH outside of the CI framework in my php.ini, virtual host or htaccess?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge - No, it's not possible. `APPPATH` is just a php constant that CI uses, not a server configuration or anything similar. As is the nature of constants, it's also not possible to redefine.

You may be barking up the wrong tree, if you can define "weird APPPATH issues" a bit more clearly, maybe we can help you resolve it.

You are of course free to run any scripts or code you want in `index.php` before defining the `$application_folder`, which may help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around using a symbolic link for the differences in my dev vs production APPPATH took care of the issue incase anyone else runs into this.